# bash: /etc/pmount.allow: Permission denied

Tags: backup

i was trying to open my ssd disk by atteching in linux based desktop system for getting data, where i tried diffrent solutions and reached at Pmount option to read data of external connected disk,

i tried this to solve [text](https://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=149597.0)pmount Error: device /dev/sdb is not removable and got this solution and stucked here

Comment: have you tried adding `sudo` to the command?